# X-Cache: MISS from log2cache.spacecom.in

Tags: cache

```
curl --head http://mashable.com
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Cache-Control: public,max-age=641,must-revalidate
X-XHR-Current-Location: /
X-Request-Id: 8b2f3be17bdbfb07d1c19879618c8ec7
X-Runtime: 0.362183
Content-Length: 92308
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cacheable: Yes
Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2013 07:47:25 GMT
X-Served-By: web1
X-Cache-Hits: 1289
X-Cache: MISS from log2cache.spacecom.in
Connection: close
```

Why do I get **X-Cache: MISS from log2cache.spacecom.in** ? Is it being cached from my ISP ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's being cached by 'Spacecom Electronics', which presumably is the company you work for (and you are browsing the Internet at work).

Comment: I don't work for 'Spacecom Electronics'. We are a small company called Epicurus.

Comment: There's something really strange going on with your network, then. Contact your network administrator.

Comment: Is it not possible, thats our ISP (maybe some parent company) ? http://www.spacecom.co.in/aboutspacecom.html

Comment: I suppose that's possible. Though their web site does not load for me.